# Python PIL - RGB pixel values for b&w pixel

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library, rgb

I would like to know whether a pixel in a b&w part of a RGB image is characterized by parameters r,g,b, s.t.
r==b==g.
Why?

Thanks a lot!
Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RGB codes of the grayscale colors (white-grays-black) consist of the same byte three times. Black is 0-0-0, white is 255-255-255, etc.

Read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale

Answer (score 3):

The conversion formula, from RGB to grey, is

L = 0.2125 * R + 0.7154 * G + 0.0721 * B

That means that there are multiple colours that can produce a single grey value.  To see why this is the case, imagine the formula had equal weights, i.e.

L = 0.333 * R + 0.333 * G + 0.333 * B = 1/3 * (R + G + B)

then L=100 could be produced by (R=0,G=150,B=150) or (R=150,G=0,B=150).